# Laravel routes for admin and users

Tags: laravel, routes

i have 2 logins pages on my project

1) cms/admin/login

2) cms/users/login

How to redirect if user to user login page 
cms/users/login

and if admin call 
cms/admin/ redirect to cms/admin/login page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't know if user is user or admin until he logs into your app, so having 2 different routes for same thing is kinda bad. To achieve something similar what you want, you will need to have one `cms/login` route where user/admin will login and depending on his status (e.g. 1 - user, 2 - admin) you redirect him on  `cms/user/page` or `cms/admin/page`. To make this you will have to use [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware) which is very good documented in Laravel official documentation.

For example your middleware for all admin pages should look like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AdminMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Run the request filter.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->input('status') == 2) {
        //2 means its admin and i let him get that admin page
           return $next($request);
        }
        //he is not admin so i redirect him back
        return Redirect::back();            
    }    
}
```

In `Kernel.php` you add middleware alias

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [        
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

And in `routes.php` you assign middleware to that routes

```
Route::get('/cms/admin/page', ['middleware' => 'admin', 'uses'=>'Controller@method']);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for post but maybe you have some examples ?

Comment: @GoranSiriev Added one simple example. It's better documented in official documentation

Comment: The 'Laravel' way of achieving this is through `Gates`. See docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization